# PHP object oriented contact form

Tags: php, oop, contact-form

My contact form is not willing to send an Email. No errors are given, but no mail is received either (I'm not working on a local server).

I'm using the Object Oriented way, not the easiest way, still it should work.. My guess is that the mail() function isn't triggered at all, but I don't understand why.

All help is deeply appreciated!

**contact.php**

```
<?php

include_once('classes/sendmail.php');

if(isset($_POST['sendmessage'])){
    try {
        $e = new Email();
        $e->Name = $_POST['name'];
        $e->Email = $_POST['email'];
        $e->Message = $_POST['message'];
        $e->Send();
    }

    catch(Exception $e){
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

if(isset($error)){
    echo $error;
}
?>


<!doctype html>
<body>


            <form name="contactform" action="" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name" />

                    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="email" />

                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" ></textarea>

                <input type="submit" class="send" value="Verzend" name="sendmessage" />
            </form>
```

**classes/sendmail.php**

```
<?php

class Email{

    private $m_sName;
    private $m_sEmail;
    private $m_sMessage;

    public function __set($p_sProperty, $p_vValue){
        switch($p_sProperty){

            case 'Name':
                if($p_vValue != '') {
                    $this->m_sName = $p_vValue;
                }
                else{
                    throw new Exception("No name found");
                }
                break;

            case 'Email':
            if($p_vValue != '') {
                    $this->m_sEmail = $p_vValue;
                }
                else{
                    throw new Exception("No email adress found");
                }
                break;

            case 'Message':
                if($p_vValue != '') {
                    $this->m_sMessage = $p_vValue;
                }
                else{
                    throw new Exception("No message found");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public function __get($p_sProperty){
        switch($p_sProperty){
            case 'Name':
                return $this->m_sName;
                break;

            case 'Email':
                return $this->m_sEmail;
                break;

            case 'Message':
                return $this->m_sMessage;
                break;
        }
    }

    public function Send(){

        $email_to = "<my Email>";
        $email_subject = "<my subject>";

        $email_message = "Name: ".$this->m_sName."\n";
        $email_message .= "Email: ".$this->m_sEmail."\n";
        $email_message .= "Message: ".$this->m_sMessage."\n";

        $headers = 'From: '.$this->m_sEmail."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$this->m_sEmail."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

    }

}

?>
```

Edit: A lot of questions were already asked about contact forms, yet no one that used OOP seemed to have the same problem as I did.

Comment: When you echo inside send() function ,what happens?

Comment: Echo what exactly? Anything pops up on top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't in the PHP class. It won't throw an error because it's not receiving any `$_POST` data. You need to remove the `enctype="text/plan"` from the `<form>`.

Should look like this when done:

```
<form name="contactform" action="" method="post">
```

Comment: You bet - happy to help

Answer (score 0):

do you have already setting smtp/sendmail before testing your form?

You can use Library PHPMailer

Example :

```
function send_email($subject, $from_mail, $message) {

            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP();  // send via SMTP
            $mail->Host     = setting_db('SMTPHOST');   // SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  // turn on 
            $mail->Username =  setting_db('SMTPUSER');  // SMTP username
            $mail->Password =  setting_db('SMTPPASSWORD'); // SMTP password
            $mail->From     =  setting_db('SMTPUSER');  // // SMTP username from
            $mail->FromName =  "Your Name";
            $mail->AddAddress($from_mail); // 
            $mail->Subject  = $subject;
            $mail->Body     = $message;
            if ($mail->send()) {
                return "OK!";
            } else {
                return "No!". $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }
```

}

And update file contact.php

```
send_email($_POST["subject"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["message"]);
```

replace

```
$e = new Email();
$e->Name = $_POST['name'];
$e->Email = $_POST['email'];
$e->Message = $_POST['message'];
$e->Send();
```

Comment: this doesn't exactly answer his issue.